# TableView with Collections

Tags: javafx-2

How am I supposed to work with Collections for 1 column? I have tried:

```
private ObservableList<EmailU> emails= FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<EmailU>());

public ObservableList<EmailU> emailsProperty() {
        return emails;
    }
```

and then

```
 col_email.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Client, ObservableList<EmailU>>("emails"));
    col_email.setCellFactory(new MultilineTextFieldCellFactory());
```

but get the following error:

```
SEVERE: javafx.scene.control.Control loadSkinClass Failed to load skin 'StringProperty [bean: TableRow[id=null, styleClass=cell indexed-cell table-row-cell], name: skinClassName, value: com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin]' for control TableRow[id=null, styleClass=cell indexed-cell table-row-cell]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper cannot be cast to javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyProperty*
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FooProperty` method should return property in terms of [javafx.beans.property.Property](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html). These properties are capable of notifying other entities about their changes which is vital for binding and TableView work. In your case it would be `ListProperty`:

```
private ListProperty<EmailU> emails = new SimpleListProperty<>(
                       FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<EmailU>()));

public ListProperty<EmailU> emailsProperty() {
    return emails;
}

public ObservableList<EmailU> getEmails() {
    return emailsProperty().get();
}

public void setEmails(ObservableList<EmailU> emails) {
    emailsProperty().set(emails);
}
```

Note you need to provide getter and setter for correct work of TableView.

Comment: This has helped me with my other issue too (with Hibernate) thanks! Here are the changes to make it work with both Hibernate and Property: `public List<EmailU> getEmails() {
            return emailsProperty().get();
        }
 
        public void setEmails(List<EmailU> emails) {
            emailsProperty().set(FXCollections.observableList(emails));
        }
        
        public ListProperty<EmailU> emailsProperty() {
            return emails;
        }`